# How to create an EC2 instance with disktype "NVMe SSD" through terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

Need to create an AWS EC2 instance of disk type "NVMe SSD" using terraform

For example: "c5d.9xlarge"

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ebs_volume says
type - (Optional) The type of EBS volume. Can be standard, gp2, gp3, io1, io2, sc1 or st1 (Default: gp2)

Tried creating an instance specifying disk type as "NVMe SSD"

Terraform complained that "NVMe SSD"  is not a supported disk type

Tried creating an "c5d.9xlarge" EC2 instance without specifying any value for disk type.
EC2 instance got created with disk type as gp2

Can someone please explain how to configure device type as "NVMe SSD"

Regards
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing EBS volumes and local EC2 ephemeral storage. NVMe SSD is not a valid option for EBS volumes. NVMe SSD local EC2 ephemeral storage are available on certain instance types and are always present when you create an instance of that type. Just by specifying `c5d.9xlarge` you will have an NVMe SSD available on the instance.

Comment: Is this maybe outdated information now? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html